# Create disk image from flash drive

Tags: mac, disk-utility

I have a 16 gb flash drive that is formatted using my mac, made bootable, and an OSX installation image put on it.  I'd like to keep that drive around so I can do it again in the future, but I don't want to keep this flash drive just laying around not being used.  I'd like to create an image of the contents so I can repurpose the drive, but be able to restore it back to it at a later point ( make it bootable again too ).

How would one go about doing that?

Comment: In Disk Utility, you can make an image from pretty much anything, and write it back to a drive at a later stage.

Answer (score 8):

1. Open Disk utility.
2. Click on any partition you want to make an image of.
3. Click "New Image" button.

That's it.